# Identification of these birds

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

We recently put up a bird house and put a camera in it. We appear to have two new neighbours, but what is the species?

We live in the south-western part of Norway.

[image: Birds]

[image: Birds]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is very likely [the great tit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_tit) (*Parvus major*).

[image]

*Photo by [Walter Baxter](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Great_tit_%28Parus_major%29_-_geograph.org.uk_-_953128.jpg).*

Comment: this is probably the most common bird in norway,if i step outside my house in daylight i will see one in less than 5 min.